# table.unpack to variadic function?

Tags: lua

Consider this test function to print arg count and type (reduction to MCVE of something else):

```
function printArgs(...)
    local args = table.pack(...)
    local str = args.n .. ' args:'
    for i=1,args.n do str = str..' '..type(args[i]) end
    print(str)
end
```

and a few basic examples:

```
printArgs(1, 's', nil)
-- 3 args: number string nil

printArgs(nil)
-- 1 args: nil
```

now I have a variable list of arguments coming from another part of my application, which I want to pass to this function, so I thought I'd use `table.unpack`:

```
printArgs(table.unpack{n=2, [1]=1, [2]='s'})
-- 2 args: number string
```

so far so good, but the following tests do not produce the expected results (should produce the same result as the first two tests):

```
printArgs(table.unpack{n=3, [1]=1, [2]='s'})
-- 2 args: number string

printArgs(table.unpack{n=1})
-- 0 args:
```

Why?
How to fix?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason is simple, `table.unpack` does not recognize `n`, its default length is `#t`.

You should use its 3rd argument to indicate the length:

```
local t = {n=3, [1]=1, [2]='s'}
printArgs(table.unpack(t, 1, t.n))
```

And you can redefine `table.unpack` to make it more elegant:

```
local unpack = table.unpack
function table.unpack(t, i, j)
    return unpack(t, i, j or t.n)
end
printArgs(table.unpack{n=3, [1]=1, [2]='s'})
```